# how would I make a navigation system that display a different forms for each item different navigation item in the same place?

Tags: javascript, forms

Basically, I am trying to make a list of buttons, that when clicked it calls a form and displays it on a spot on a page, then when another button is clicked, the form that was displayed previously disappears and a new form replaces it.

I understand that with the button you can use:

```
    onClick="document.getElementbyId('form1').style.display=('inline')"
```

but how would I go about setting the display for none on the current one, and then changing it? I have around 25+ forms, so it needs to be dynamic and sets whatever form is currently displaying to display none, and then set the form defined to display.

Hopefully you guys understand what I am trying to accomplish. A list with a bunch of links that display different forms, but I only want one form to display at the same time, and all in the exact same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try This Code:    


<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="page1" class="tab">page 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="page2" class="tab">page 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3" id="page3" class="tab">page 3</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4" id="page4" class="tab">page 4</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5" id="page5" class="tab">page 5</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="contentarea" id="response"></div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        // load index page when the page loads
        $("#response").html("DEFAULT");
        $("#page1").click(function () {
            // load home page on click
            $("#response").html("TESTING 1");
        });
        $("#page2").click(function () {
            // load about page on click
            $("#response").html("TESTING 2");
        });
        $("#page3").click(function () {
            // load contact form onclick
            $("#response").html("TESTING 3");
        });
        $("#page4").click(function () {
            // load contact form onclick
            $("#response").html("TESTING 4");
        });
        $("#page5").click(function () {
            // load contact form onclick
            $("#response").html("TESTING 5");
        });
    });

    </script>

    <style>
    li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
li a {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    padding: 4px;
}

   </style>
```

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks.